# Best practices for deserializing nullable types

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization, nullable

I want to deserialize the following xml:

```
<Root>
    <Order> 
        <Id>12</Id>
        <Date>2013-03-28T16:12:45</Date>
        <Number></Number>
        <Amount></Amount>
    </Order>
</Root>
```

My class is similar to this:

```
    [XmlType("Order")]
    public class ImportOrder
    {
        [XmlElement("Id")]
        public int OrderId { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Date")]
        public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Number")]
        public string OrderNumber { get; set; }   

        [XmlElement("Amount", IsNullable = true)]
        public decimal? OrderAmount { get; set; }
    }
```

The deserializer I use:

```
        public List<T> DeserializeList<T>(string filePath, string rootName)
        {
            var itemList = new List<T>();

            if (File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<T>), new XmlRootAttribute(rootName));
                TextReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath);
                itemList = (List<T>)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                reader.Close();
            }

            return itemList;
        }
```

It works fine when all data is filled in the xml. If `Number` is empty it is ok too.
But when `Amount` is empty I get exception:

```
Input string was not in a correct format.
```

It's because you cannot simply deserialize nullable types. 
I found multiple solutions in the internet to solve this problem. But they don't look very well and you have to write a lot of code for this.

**Are there any elegant solution? What is best practices for deserializing nullable types?**

Comment: look at this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3250706/xmlserializer-and-nullable-attributes - the answer about implementing IXmlSerializable and doing it yourself

Comment: @Axarydax, I have to agree there, that's effectively the only way.

Answer (score 0):

Is there an specific need to have the XML in the specific way that you have it right there?

I'm asking this because if you are already telling the XML deserializer that the element Amount is nullable, this means that the element could exists or not. So if you are generating the XML you only need to avoid generating this element and you are ready to go.

You can see that if you have a file like this:

```
<Root>
    <Order> 
        <Id>12</Id>
        <Date>2013-03-28T16:12:45</Date>
        <Number></Number>
    </Order>
</Root>
```

And you parse it with your code it will work.

Comment: No, input xml always has tag <Amount> but sometimes it is emty. Using IsNullable I have just tried to solve my problem.